# Calculating difference in cursor position

Tags: javascript

I want to create something that loops through and shows each of some images when the user moves the mouse across the screen.

I initially tried to use the `onmouseover` event to increment a value each time the user moved the mouse. The goal was to increment the "image loop index" when the mouse has moved a set amount of pixels from the last initial position. However, this method was not working as the event doesn't register every little pixel moved when moving the mouse fast.

So I ended up using `event.pageX` and `event.pageY` instead, storing these values in `initX` and `initY`, then comparing the summed value of these two with two variables storing the new value (`tempX` and `tempY`) using `Math.abs((initX + initY), (tempX + tempY)) > limit`, where `limit` is a set value of difference. If the new X and Y values differ more than `limit`, `initX` and `initY` is defined again with the current X and Y position and a function shows the next image.

Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tobias_kh/d3gv2ybo/

It's working like intended, but I realized that as the function is comparing the difference in pixels between `(initX + initY)` and `(tempX + tempY)`, moving the mouse diagonally creates a smaller difference which results in it reaching the limit slower than moving the mouse strictly horizontally or vertically.

Is there some other way of doing this comparison? The optimal result would be if it just strictly looks at the amount of pixels moved instead of comparing the old and new position of the mouse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understand, you need to calculate distance between two points here (hypotenuse in most cases). So you can use this function for comparison between two points:

```js
function calculatePixelDistance(initX, initY, tempX, tempY) {
        return Math.sqrt(Math.pow((initX - tempX), 2) + Math.pow((initY - tempY), 2));
}
```

The Pythagorean Theorem